# Renesas USB3 uPD720201 not listed under USB3 root hub

Tags: usb

I have an issue with Renesas uPD720201 which appears to be performing at USB2.0 speeds.

lspci -v shows

```
03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fe500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

where it indicates that the driver is xhci_hcd

However, on lsusb -t, it is not attached to the USB3 host controller

As can see listed under a USB2 root hub.

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

On another PC running the same version of Ubuntu but with a different brand USB3 card, I can see the USB device listed under the xhci_hcd root hub.

Any ideas why this is so?

Thanks

lsusb shows

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c06a Logitech, Inc. USB Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13fe:5500 Kingston Technology Company Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

SOLUTION: The issue was due to the fact that the USB device was found plugged in to a USB2 port rather than to ports on the PCIe card. @Terrance's comment below helped resolve it simply by plugging the USB drive to the PCIe ports.

Comment: According to your output, your USB drive is not connected to the USB 3.0 controller.  What is the output of `lsusb` without any switches?  You will see a Bus and Device that your USB drive is connected to.  My guess is it will show something like `Bus 001 Device 004`.  When connected to the right port is should be `Bus 004 Device 001` or something close to that.

Comment: @Terrance, I have a USB3 hub connected to the PCIe card. But both the hub (device 003) and the USB drive (device 004) are listed as connected to bus 001 and the for some strange reason bus 001 device 002 is listed as an Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub.

Comment: Connect your USB drive directly to the controller itself without the hub then and see.

Comment: Oops...operator error. Pulled the PC out from the closet and checked.....You were spot on! It was connected to the wrong card. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please remove "solved" from title and post solution as answer.